# Filter list from database using in-memory list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, inner-join

I have a generic list of employees, fetched using a WCF web service, and a SQL table with expense reports. I have an index page with a list of expense reports and I want to display the employee name in the list, but the employee name is not stored in the expense report table, only the employee Id. Normally, I would use a join between the employees and the expense reports but I have found that I cannot join an in-memory data set (employees) to a SQL database call (expense reports). I get an error about primitive types.

It appears my only option is to either get all the employees first, then iterate through the expense reports to find matching employee Ids, or get all the expense reports first and iterate through them and get the employee information. The problem is, in some cases I may have thousands of rows in each side of the equation. Doing either would be highly inefficient.

So my question is, am I missing something and is there a way to efficiently join a in-memory data set to a SQL database call or is my only option to denormalize my database and store the information in the SQL table?

Comment: Are you using a database first approach ? or a code first with entity framework ?

Answer (score 0):

This would be *much* easier if you actually provided some code to work with. However, you simply need to query by something like a list of ids, rather than the full employee objects. Something along the lines of:

```
var employeeIds = employees.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
var expenses = db.Expenses.Where(m => employeeIds.Contains(m.EmployeeId));
```

Again, no code to work with, so you'll obviously need to adapt that to your actual class and property names.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention there's perhaps thousands of records so you'll have some sort of paging? I'd first pull out the records from DB then do a query against the employee list. If you put a .ToList() behind your result from DB then it will execute the SQL that fetch the result and will be loaded into memeory. That is if you're using a ORM like entity framework or linq to sql.

```
var itemsPage = 50;
var expensesPage = expenses
  .Skip(itemsPage * pageNumber)
  .Take(itemsPage)
  .ToList();

var result = expensesPage
  .Join(employees,
    exp => exp.EmployeeId,
    emp => emp.Id,
    (expense, employee) => new ExpenseViewModel { employee.Name, expense.Expenses }
  );
```

If there thousands of Employees too then I'd change to WCF service to also accept a list over employee ids that will return a list over employees you asked for and use that.